# Find the order $\bar{5} + H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups

> Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\langle 6+ 18\mathbb{Z}\rangle= \langle \bar{6}\rangle $ a subgroup of $G$. Consider the group $G/H$. What is the order of $(5 + 18 \mathbb{Z}) + H \in G/H$?

**Attempt:**

We know that as $G$ is a commutative group, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. So all we have to do is to find the smaller integer $n$ such that $n(5 + 18 \mathbb{Z}) + H = H$. The smaller $n$ here is 18. So $ord(\bar{5} + H) = 18$.

I am just a bit confused here. According to Lagrange Theorem, the order of an element divide the order of the group. However, the order of the group is 6, but 18 does not divide 6. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Write down the six element of $G/H$ explicitly. One element is $\overline{5}$. Compute $\overline{5}+\overline{5}$. Which element is it? Go on like this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you clarify how you computed that the order of $5 + H$ is $18$? What is the definition you know of "order"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative answer, trying to bring structure in the game. We have the short exact sequence:
$$
0
\longrightarrow
\underbrace{6\Bbb Z/18\Bbb Z}_{H}
\longrightarrow
\underbrace{\Bbb Z/18\Bbb Z}_{G}
\longrightarrow
\underbrace{\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z}_{G/H}
\longrightarrow
0
\ .
$$
The image of that complicated element $5 + 18 \mathbb{Z}\in G$ inside $G/H$,
so
$$
(5 + 18 \mathbb{Z}) + H = (5 + 18 \mathbb{Z}) + (6\Bbb Z+18\Bbb Z) = (5 + 6\Bbb Z) 
\in G/H\ ,
$$
is simply $5+6\Bbb Z$, an element of order six.

Answer (score 2):

Observe, that $H=\{-6+18\mathbb Z, 18\mathbb Z, 6+18\mathbb Z\}$. Hence, $|G/H|=[G:H]=18:3=6$. Now:
\begin{align*}\overline{5}&=5+H=\{-1+18\mathbb Z, 5+18\mathbb Z, 11+18\mathbb Z\}\\\overline{5}+\overline{5}&=10+H=\{4+18\mathbb Z, 10+18\mathbb Z, -2+18\mathbb Z\}\\\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}&=15+H=\{9+18\mathbb Z, 15+18\mathbb Z, 3+18\mathbb Z\}.\end{align*}
None of these is $H$. But you can easily calculate $\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}$. Is it $H$ or not?

Comment: $\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5}+\overline{5} = \overline{30}$ which is not $H$. How does your answer help?

Comment: How does $\overline{30}$ looks like? Which elements does it contain? Please think about it :)

Comment: The elements are $\overline{30} + 18 \mathbb{Z}$, $\overline{36} + 18 \mathbb{Z}$ and $\overline{42} + 18 \mathbb{Z}$ which is not $H$

Comment: There is no need for an overline. Are you sure? Isn't $30+18\mathbb Z$ in $H$?

Comment: Pretty sure it is not $H$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not convinced. Why not? I am very sure $30+18\mathbb Z\in H$,

Comment: @labrecque Explicitly write out some elements of $30+18 \Bbb Z$.  When you do so, remember that $\Bbb Z$ contains negative integers.  After doing that, see if you still think that $30 + 18 \Bbb Z \notin H$.  Because I agree with Jochen.